# Intersection ratio between 2 polygons in SymPy

Tags: sympy

Can I calculate intersection ratio between 2 polygons in **SymPy** ?

(I know, that it can be done with shapely)
If there is a simple way of calculating the are of **Segement2D**, it will be also enough.

```
from sympy import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1, p2, p3, p4 = [(0, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1), (0, 1)]
q1, q2, q3, q4 = [(1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (1,1)]
pol1 = Polygon(p1, p2, p3, p4)
pol2 = Polygon(q1, q2, q3, q4)

plt.fill([p1[0], p2[0], p3[0], p4[0]], [p1[1], p2[1], p3[1], p4[1]], alpha=.5)
plt.fill([q1[0], q2[0], q3[0], q4[0]], [q1[1], q2[1], q3[1], q4[1]], alpha=.5)

print (pol2.intersection(pol1))
#  >> [Segment2D(Point2D(1, 0), Point2D(2, 0)), Segment2D(Point2D(2, 1), Point2D(1, 1))]
```

In shapeley this would be like this:

```
pol2.intersection(pol1).area / pol2.area
```

Can I do the the same in Sympy, easily ?

[image]

Comment: What do YOU mean by "intersection ratio"?  You have 100% of q, and 2/9 of p.

Comment: @TimRoberts, any of them. For example, to calculate for the q.

Comment: I don't think SymPy geometry module is advanced enough to solve this task. Sure, the `Polygon` class offers the `intersection` method, which however returns only segments and point of the boundaries of intersection, not regions. To understand what I mean, you can offset vertically `pol2` by 0.5, then execute `pol1.intersection(pol2)`, which returns a single segment, which clearly is not enough for your needs.

Comment: @Davide_sd, I assume, that it's possible to create a Polygon manually from intersection / boundaries. And then calculate it. But I didn't succeed in getting access to points inside Segement2D.

Comment: That's the easy part, just use `your_segment.args`.

Answer (score 0):

For a convex intersection area you could use the `convex_hull` around the points. Let `i` be your intersection, then:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> convex_hull(*[j for s in i for j in s.args])
Polygon(Point2D(1, 0), Point2D(2, 0), Point2D(2, 1), Point2D(1, 1))
```